# The font of the comments change after one adds/edits a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments, articles

I noticed that after adding (or editing) a comment on articles, the font of the entire comments thread changes and remains changed until the page is refreshed.

Here's how it normally looks:

[image: Font size normally looks larger]

And this is how it looks after adding/editing a comment:

[image: Font size becomes smaller after adding/editing a comment]

Comment: The comment text is too large on initial render (compare it there to the way it looks on normal posts). There must be a style messed up somewhere, which the submission of the comment is finding with JavaScript.

Comment: a field test shows that on initial load an `fs-body2` class is added to the `.comment-text` node for some reason which makes the text look huge. It is removed when the comment section updates after submitting the comment.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I noticed that but I assumed that it was an intentional design difference between articles and regular posts. But I think you're right. It makes sense that _that_ is likely the bug.

Comment: @jdstack Thank you for the fix. Did you consider Cody's comment above though? Is the large font size an intentional design difference compared to comments on regular posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for logging this bug, the developers have been made aware and will look into it.

**Update 2021-08-09**

This bug is fixed and should not occur anymore